# What is attacker trying to do with my server?

Tags: server, file-inclusion

Some is trying to access this link (and similar ones) frequently in my site:

http://example.com/upload/RS=%5EADAJVxZ5NB.GMTgFV3EMEJX3sN22Jw-

Note that my server doesn't have an upload folder inside of it, but it allows users to upload videos. So it is redirecting the attacker to a 404 page.

So what is the attacker trying to do? And what does seeing this link mean?

Comment: My guess: doorknob rattling.  I frequently get requests for `something.dll` on my CentOS site.  Something has a vulnerability that's triggered by that URL, and several attackers are spinning through IP address blocks looking for victims.  I hope someone will come along to tell us what vulnerability is indicated by that URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a botnet trying the "doors" as Bob has suggested. From time-to-time, vulnerabilities appear in standard software that allows attackers access via supposedly innocuous entry points.

If you don't already have it installed, I would recommend something like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which will automatically ban source IP's that make attempts to get to vulnerable ports/locations.

`fail2ban` can be also configured with manual checks to filter out new vulnerabilities and annoyances.